# Email multiple rows to one recipient based on category values using Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm looking for:

I am working on a spreadsheet that contains transaction information for multiple people. Some people have only 1 transaction (1 row of information) while others may have multiple transactions (rows of information). So far, the code I am working on is able send an email containing one transaction per email. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to group multiple transactions into one email. One of the column fields is "Email address" and ideally I could use that to group multiple rows. Pretty much a mail merge that can be grouped by a column in the spread sheet or by the identification of similar values.

What I've tried/what I'm thinking:

I already have the code sort by email address so that the transactions for each person are consecutive on the sheet. I am thinking that I need to loop with an if statement saying something along the lines "if the next value in the 'email address' field is the same as the previous one, add a new line in the body of the email." From what I have researched I might need to do a loop within a loop for the email body but I am not completely sure how to go about that. In the code I have, I have already somewhat formatted the email the way it should be.

Disclaimer:
I'm pretty new to coding so any help is appreciated. I am unsure how to loop in the body of the message and eventually exit once the script hits a different person. I'd like to do it all in GAS.

This is what I've got so far:

```js
var SENT = "Y";

function sendEmails() {

  //This section specifies the sheet and some definitions we are working with

  var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startrow = 4;  // First row of data to process
  var numrows = lastrow;   // Number of rows to process
  sheet.sort(14, true);   //Sorts the sheet by email address

  //This section formats the columns so they appear correctly in the html email below

  var column = sheet.getRange("K4:L");
  column.setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // Simple date format 

  var column = sheet.getRange("M:M");
  column.setNumberFormat("@"); // Simple plain text format

  var column = sheet.getRange("K4:L");
  column.setNumberFormat("@"); // Simple plain text format 

  var column = sheet.getRange("E:E");
  column.setNumberFormat("$0.00"); // Simple currency format   

  //This section specifies the actual data we will be working with

  var datarange = sheet.getRange(startrow, 1, lastrow, 15)// Fetch the range of cells
  var data = datarange.getValues();// Fetch values for each row in the Range.

  //Defining column data

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var col = data[i];
    var firstname = col[2];   // Column starting at 0 from left to right
    var expamount = col[4];   // Column starting at 0 from left to right
    var subdate = col[10];   // Column starting at 0 from left to right
    var trandate = col[11];   // Column starting at 0 from left to right
    var reportname = col[12];   // Column starting at 0 from left to right
    var emailaddress = col[13];  // Column starting at 0 from left to right
    var emailsent = col[14];   //Column starting at 0 from left to right
    var subject = "MinistryCard Expenses Over 90 Days";   // Subject for the email to be sent
    var emailintro =   // Introduction part of the email

          'Hi ' + firstname + ', <br /><br />' +

          'This is the introduction to the email.' +

          'The related expenses are below: <br /><br/ >'

    var emailtrans = //THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE THE MAGIC TO HAPPEN... I THINK

          '<strong>Report Name: </strong>' + reportname + '  <br /><strong>Transaction Date: </strong>' + trandate + '  <br /><strong>Transaction Amount: </strong>' + expamount +
          '  <br /><strong>Approval Date: </strong>' + subdate + '<br /><br />'

    var emailend =   // The endd of the email

          'We apologize for any inconvenience this may cause. ' +
          'Also, please contact us if you believe you are recieving this email in error. Thank you. <br /><br /><br />' +

          'Enjoy your day, <br /><br />'

    //The section below retrieves alias email address to send as

    var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();// Log the aliases for this Gmail account and send an email as the first one.
    var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases(); // Gets the alias ministrycard@cru.org from account
      Logger.log(aliases);  // Logs the alias

    // The section below sends the actual emails

     if (emailaddress != "" && emailsent != SENT){
       if (aliases.length > 0){  // Prevents sending duplicates

      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress, subject , emailintro + emailtrans + emailend, {'from': aliases[0],'replyto': 'ministrycard@cru.org', htmlBody : emailintro + emailtrans + emailend});
        sheet.getRange(startrow + i, 15).setValue(SENT);
          SpreadsheetApp.flush();  // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted


       }} else {    }}}
```

Comment: Welcome. Ideally questions should include a brief description of your search/research efforts and include the minimum lines of code to show what you already tried. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple solutions. Here's mine:

declare a `nextEmail` variable before the main for loop begins.

```
var nextEmail = '';
```

at the beginning of the loop, set `nextEmail` to the email in the next row:

```
if (i < data.length - 1) {
  nextEmail = data[i+1][13]//looks at next row, 13th column
} else {//catch if i is the maximum row
  nextEmail = ''
}
```

add another conditional that checks that the next email address is not the same before sending the email

```
if (emailaddress != "" && emailsent != SENT && nextEmail != emailaddress){
```

You didn't seem to specify what parts of the message you want to change each time and what parts you want to stay the same, but I'm assuming you want to change only `emailtrans`.

now, instead of declaing a new variable `emailtrans` each time it loops around, declare `emailtrans` before the loop as an empty string...

```
var emailtrans = ''
```

...and instead append the big string to `emailtrans`

```
emailtrans += 

      '<strong>Report Name: </strong>' + reportname + '  <br /><strong>Transaction Date: </strong>' + trandate + '  <br /><strong>Transaction Amount: </strong>' + expamount +
      '  <br /><strong>Approval Date: </strong>' + subdate + '<br /><br />';
```

and then set `emailtrans` to an empty string right after you send the email, inside of the if statement.

```
emailtrans = ''
```

---

---

There are a few things you didn't ask about but I still think should be addressed. You probably would have caught a lot of this if only you tested whatever you've got, even if it's incomplete, to make sure it did what you want before asking for help.

SENT variable should probably be declared within the function (good practice)

`numrows` is only equal to `lastrow` if `startrow` is zero. Set `numrows` to `lastrow - startrow` and use `numrows` instead of `lastrow` when you declare `datarange`.

You sort the whole sheet based on column M, but your script only collect data from row 4 onward. Depending on your labels in rows 1-3, the sorting might place some emails in rows 1-3 and your labels in row 4 and onward. Instead, I'm guessing you only want to sort the range containing the emails, so do a `.sort()` on that range instead of the whole sheet.

Putting in semicolons where you define `emailintro`, `emailtrans`, and `emailend` in multiple lines is probably a good idea.

I could be wrong, but it seems the html tags aren't formatted right. `<br /><br />` wouldn't insert a break ... they would just end two breaks?

Declaring a variable inside a for loop is bad practice. Declare it outside the loop beforehand, and set it (`thing = value`), not declare it (`var thing = value`), inside the loop.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and thanks for the good practice tips!! I will edit it now. I have the code starting at row 4 because there are 3 rows of headers (not by choice) that do not include data. When the code sorts, it leaves rows 1-3 unaffected and sorts starting at row 4. As for the semicolons, thanks! I put them in. Also, the <br /> was recommend from another site. It works in adding line breaks after each section (like hitting enter). Last but not least, thanks for the declaration tips, I will implement that as well! Really appreciate it! Going to try this out, will keep you posted!

Comment: Hi @Quaris, I tried the corrections and I think it's almost there! The only issue I'm having now is that the email is sending all previous transactions and not sending transactions unique to the email address. For example, if Person A has 4 transactions (row 1-4) and Person B has 3 transactions (rows 5-7), Person A gets and email with transaction rows 1-4 (as they should) and Person B gets an email with 7 transactions from rows 1-7. Any ideas? I tried moving the email loop around but to no avail. Much closer with you help earlier though, thanks again!

Comment: Are you resetting the variable emailtrans to an empty string right after you send an email? (`emailtrans = ''`)

Comment: Hi @Quaris, yes I am. This is what the loop section looks like. Ive been trying to write all the checks/loops out on paper but having trouble with it. Thanks again for the help. Basically I initialize my variables (including the emailtrans +=), open a for loop, in the for loop i have an if statement with the nextemail section, the if statement is closed then the send email if statement is there and the emailtrans is set to "".

Comment: Seeing your actual code would help a lot. Could you link me a sample spreadsheet or something?

Comment: Hi again @Quaris, it works! There was a mix up below but with you guidance on good practice I was able to correct the issue. I really appreciate your help! Thanks again!