# Google Sheet Script: Send multiple HTML-formatted rows as one email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

*EDIT: "CODE 2" accomplishes what I want except until the quota is hit. I removed the now irrelevant "CODE 1".*

**OBJECTIVE: To iterate over multiple spreadsheet rows, format each row using HTML and send the formatted version of each row to one email address.**

*WHAT* is the problem?:

I can loop through everything and combine all rows into one email, but it sends emails until the quota is hit and now I can't test this further.

*WHY* am I trying to do this?: To create a more accurate MLA 8 bibliography. Think of a more accurate EasyBib that I can edit to my liking.

*WHO* else could make use of this?: Sending multiple rows in a mail-merge to one address is useful, but so is this formatting workaround. This lets me edit parts of a string automatically using HTML. Using built-in functions (and what I can find here via script) it is not possible to append strings together, format each individually and have the output retain the original formatting of each string.

*HOW* have I tried to solve this?: See two codes below. I started working off of the solution provided [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613960/email-multiple-rows-to-one-recipient-based-on-category-values-using-apps-script). I tried to limit the number of columns processed (so that the email address wasn't relevant at all), but that's what caused me to hit the quota. This is as far as I could get in about 3 hours and now I can't test further due to a screw up and hitting the quota.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.

*WHERE* can you try it out?: If it helps, [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BItPuRU3nUlNE-Eu0Bnottj7i8Rpu4AAH-seU51MmX8/edit?usp=sharing) is an edit-able copy of the sheet in question.

*DISCLAIMER*: I'm new to this so speak slowly with small words haha. Also, I apologize if I don't get back on this right away, the next 12 hours or so are about to get a bit hectic. *In all seriousness, I appreciate any help that can point me in the right direction!*

CODE 2

```
//This constant is used to format the date and time as "09/20/1900 11:20 AM"
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"EST", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");

// var EMAIL_SENT = ("Email Sent");


function mlaTest2() {

// Sheet Information
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('test'));
  var startRow = 3;  
  var startCol = 21; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;  
  var numCols = 14; 


  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols);
  var dataRange2 = sheet.getRange(3,22,numRows,3);

  var message = '';
  var html = '';

// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var cells = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(cells);

  //var i in cells
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {

    var column = cells[i];
    var colU = column[0];           
    var colV = column[1];           
    var colW = column[2];           
    var colX = column[3];           
    var colY = column[4];          
    var colZ = column[5];           
    var colAA = column[6];          
    var colAB = column[7];           
    var colAC = column[8];
    var colAD = column[9];
    var colAE = column[10];
    var colAF = column[11];
    var colAG = column[12];
    var colAH = column[13];

// The columns below don't contain citation data    
//    var colAI = column[14];
//    var colAJ = column[15];
//    var colAK = column[16];

      var author1 = colU;
      var author2 = colV;
      var author3 = colW;
      var title1Quotes = colX;
      var title2Italics = colY;
      var containerItalics = colZ;
      var contribution1 = colAA;
      var contribution2 = colAB;
      var contribution3 = colAC;
      var version = colAD;
      var number = colAE;
      var publisher = colAF;
      var pubDate = colAG;
      var location = colAH;

 // The columns belw don't contain citation data
      var emailAddress = 'nathaniel.omar.davis@gmail.com';
   //   var sent = colAJ;
      var subject = "test";

  //  if (sent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates

     // Format text as html   
     html +=
      '<p>' + author1 +  
      author2 + 
      author3 + 
      title1Quotes + 
      '<i>' + title2Italics + containerItalics + '</i>' + 
      contribution1 + 
      contribution2 + 
      contribution3 + 
      version + 
      number + 
      publisher + 
      pubDate +
      location+
      '<br> </p>'
      Logger.log(html);
      ;

      var replyTo = 'coachnod@outlook.com'
      var bcc = ''
      var cc = ''
      var sender = 'Nate Davis'


//Send the emails
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
      name: sender, 
      replyTo: replyTo, 
      htmlBody: html
      });

//Update the sheet
 //     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 36).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
 //     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 37).setValue(formattedDate);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question Clarification EDIT:** The `MailApp.sendMail()` function is inside the `for` loop so the script will try to send an email in every iteration of the for loop. Bringing the `sendMail()` function out of the for loop will only send one email.

Side note: Also within the html += assignment you have a `Logger.log(html);` before the end of the statement.

---

```
function mlaTest2() {

  // Sheet Information
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('test'));
  var startRow = 3;  
  var startCol = 21; 
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;  
  var numCols = 14; 


  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numCols);
  var dataRange2 = sheet.getRange(3,22,numRows,3);

  var message = '';
  var html = '';

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var cells = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(cells);

  //var i in cells
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; ++i) {

    var column = cells[i];
    var colU = column[0];           
    var colV = column[1];           
    var colW = column[2];           
    var colX = column[3];           
    var colY = column[4];          
    var colZ = column[5];           
    var colAA = column[6];          
    var colAB = column[7];           
    var colAC = column[8];
    var colAD = column[9];
    var colAE = column[10];
    var colAF = column[11];
    var colAG = column[12];
    var colAH = column[13];

    // The columns below don't contain citation data    
    //var colAI = column[14];
    //var colAJ = column[15];
    //var colAK = column[16];

      var author1 = colU;
      var author2 = colV;
      var author3 = colW;
      var title1Quotes = colX;
      var title2Italics = colY;
      var containerItalics = colZ;
      var contribution1 = colAA;
      var contribution2 = colAB;
      var contribution3 = colAC;
      var version = colAD;
      var number = colAE;
      var publisher = colAF;
      var pubDate = colAG;
      var location = colAH;

      //The columns belw don't contain citation data
      var emailAddress = 'nathaniel.omar.davis@gmail.com';
     //var sent = colAJ;
      var subject = "test";

     //if (sent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates

     //Format text as html   
     html +=
      '<p>' + author1 +  
      author2 + 
      author3 + 
      title1Quotes + 
      '<i>' + title2Italics + containerItalics + '</i>' + 
      contribution1 + 
      contribution2 + 
      contribution3 + 
      version + 
      number + 
      publisher + 
      pubDate +
      location+
      '<br> </p>';
      Logger.log(html);

      var replyTo = 'coachnod@outlook.com'
      var bcc = ''
      var cc = ''
      var sender = 'Nate Davis'

//Update the sheet
 //     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 36).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
 //     sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 37).setValue(formattedDate);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    } //FOR LOOP ENDS HERE

  //SEND ONE EMAIL
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    name: sender, 
    replyTo: replyTo, 
    htmlBody: html
  });
}
```

Comment: Chris, I already had it working that it DOES NOT send if an email address isn't present "CODE 1." I want each row with data present to show up in the same email; Am I correct that "+=" does that? When I had used just "=" it logged each row individually, which meant individual emails. "CODE 2" accomplishes what I want, but send emails until the quota is hit.

Comment: Chris, I want "CODE 2" to only send to one email address, one time when i hit "run." I have "CODE 1" there because that kinda of worked too, but I'm not sure which option will provide me with a solution. I'm on my way out the door for a while but if you (or any other readers) have any other tips or things I should try, I'll do so once I return. Thanks for your time! I apologize in advance if  I see your comment but don't get to reply right away.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. To address the emails already not sending correctly it seems like it would actually just error out as no email would be provided?
As far as `Code 2`,  because the `sendMail()` function is inside the for loop it will try to send an email for every column in your sheet. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I haven't had a chance to look over this yet. I'll work it in the logger now, but I'll have to wait to try to send an actual email until tomorrow when the quota resets. I'll leave this open until then. Once I can test it more I'll get back to you. Thanks again for your time and help!

Comment: Worked perfectly. All that and it was just putting the sendMail function inside the for loop. Thanks for your help!